# Два курсора через CursorLoader

Tags: android

Как подключить два курсора через cursorloader? Пока что имею следующее

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private AutoCompleteTextView txtSearch;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private ListView list;
    private ImageButton btnClear;

    DBHeler db;

    private MyCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DBHeler(this);

        try {
            db.createDataBase();
            db.openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        // Настраиваем адаптер
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter =
                ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Вызываем адаптер
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        txtSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        btnClear = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

        /*Выводим в список все слова, при запуске программы*/
        String selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (selectedItem.equals("С русского на английский")) {
            cursorAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, 0);
            list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        } else if (selectedItem.equals("С английского на русский")) {
            cursorAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, 0);
            list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        txtSearch.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b && txtSearch.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                if(charSequence.length() != 0){
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SlovoActivity.class);
                CharSequence strCharSequence = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtSlovo)).getText();
                String str = strCharSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                String selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (selectedItem.equals("С русского на английский")) {
                    intent.putExtra("slovo", str);
                    intent.putExtra("type", "RU");
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (selectedItem.equals("С английского на русский")) {
                    intent.putExtra("slovo", str);
                    intent.putExtra("type", "EN");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                txtSearch.setText("");
                String str = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                if (str.equals("С русского на английский")) {
                    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, MainActivity.this);
                } else if (str.equals("С английского на русский")) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // закрываем подключение при выходе
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        DBHeler db;
        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DBHeler db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getRuWords();
            return cursor;
        }

    }
}
```

Мне нужно чтобы при выборе из spinner значения "С русского на английский" в listView выводились данные из курсора db.getRuWords(),  а если выбрать значение "С английского на русский", чтобы выводились данные из курсора db.getEnWords(). как должен выглядеть код я все не пойму?

СДЕЛАЛА ТАК. НО НЕ РАБОТАЕТ все равно

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private AutoCompleteTextView txtSearch;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private ListView list;
    private ImageButton btnClear;

    private final int RULOADER = 1;
    private final int ENLOADER = 1;

    DBHeler db;

    private MyCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DBHeler(this);

        try {
            db.createDataBase();
            db.openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        // Настраиваем адаптер
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter =
                ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Вызываем адаптер
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        txtSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        btnClear = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

        /*Выводим в список все слова, при запуске программы*/
        String selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (selectedItem.equals("С русского на английский")) {
            cursorAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, 0);
            list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        } else if (selectedItem.equals("С английского на русский")) {
            cursorAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, 0);
            list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        txtSearch.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b && txtSearch.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                if(charSequence.length() != 0){
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SlovoActivity.class);
                CharSequence strCharSequence = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtSlovo)).getText();
                String str = strCharSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                String selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (selectedItem.equals("С русского на английский")) {
                    intent.putExtra("slovo", str);
                    intent.putExtra("type", "RU");
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (selectedItem.equals("С английского на русский")) {
                    intent.putExtra("slovo", str);
                    intent.putExtra("type", "EN");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                txtSearch.setText("");
                String str = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                if (str.equals("С русского на английский")) {
                    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(RULOADER, null, MainActivity.this);
                    list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
                } else if (str.equals("С английского на русский")) {
                    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(ENLOADER, null, MainActivity.this);
                    list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // закрываем подключение при выходе
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        if (id == RULOADER) {
            return new RuWords(MainActivity.this, db);
        } else {
            return new EnWords(MainActivity.this, db);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        //cursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        if(loader instanceof RuWords) {
            cursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        } else {
            cursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }

    static class RuWords extends CursorLoader {
        DBHeler db;
        public RuWords(Context context, DBHeler db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getRuWords();
            return cursor;
        }
    }

    static class EnWords extends CursorLoader {
        DBHeler db;
        public EnWords(Context context, DBHeler db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getEnWords();
            return cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

Что не так?

Comment: два класса наследника от CursorLoader создавать что ли?

Comment: [Этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/611940/177345) нужно удалить, так он в принципе такой-же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно такой код, оставлены только важные для примера части активити (тестировать мне не на чем, к сожалению, поэтому возможны мелкие недочеты). ID в методах и аргументах указывает, какой из загрузчиков использовать в данный момент.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private Spinner spinner;
    private ListView list;
    static final  int LOADER_RUS = 0;
    static final int LOADER_ENG = 1;

    DBHeler db;

    private MyCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DBHeler(this);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        from = new String[] {Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE};
        to = new int[] {R.id.txtBukva, R.id.txtSlovo, R.id.btnIzbrannoe};
        cursorAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
        list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        // инициализируем оба загрузчика   
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_RUS, null, this);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ENG, null, this);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int loadID, long l) {

                // обновляем данные в курсоре
                getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(loadID).forceLoad();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });


    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        Cursor cursor;
        DBHeler db;
        final int LoaderID;
        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DBHeler db, int id) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
            LoaderID = id;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
          switch (LoaderID) {
                case LOADER_RUS: cursor = db.getRuWords();
                       break;
                case LOADER_ENG: cursor = db.getEnWords();
                       break;
          }
        return cursor;
        }

    }
}
```

`MyCursorLoader` принимает третьим аргументом ID, какой из курсоров подключать.

При выборе пункта в спинере обновление загрузчика происходит по нажатой позиции (а не по содержимому пункта списка) - третий аргумент колбэка с именем `loadID` в данном коде передает позицию выбранного пункта. Позиция может быть 0 или 1, ID наших загрузчиков так же 0 или 1 для русского и английского набора соответственно.

Comment: в case где LOADER_RUS и LOADER_ENG ругается пишет

Non-static field 'LOADER_RUS' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: @Вероника сделайте эти константы `static`.Они вообще для удобства восприятия, вместо них можете указывать число 0 и 1

Comment: да, уже сделала. Но мне кажется что это

from = new String[] {Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE};
        to = new int[] {R.id.txtBukva, R.id.txtSlovo, R.id.btnIzbrannoe};
        cursorAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0); лишнее. В классе-адаптере у меня так сделано holder.txtBukva.setText(bukva);
        holder.txtSlovo.setText(slovo);  bukva, slovo получаю из курсора. а адаптер наследуется от cursoradapter. или ваш вариант получше в плане производительности и т.д.?

Comment: @Вероника если ваш адаптер получает данные другим способом, то инициализируйте его и передавайте те данные, которые предусмотрены вашим адаптером. Это пример.