# Как spinner заполнить данными выборки из SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-spinner, cursoradaper

Есть база SQLite с таблицей   и spinner'ы в которых должны отображаться уникальные (группированые) строки по столбцам (категория,продукт,описание), в моем понимании для этого надо создать запрос, курсор по нему получает требуемую инфу и заполняет ей спиннер, но почему то так не выходит. Сделал по другому: создал отдельно таблицу со столбцом категории которая наполняется с помощью диалога, создал метод который все данные с таблицы заполняет в List, а с листа заполняется уже спиннер...

```
 public List<String> getDirectory_Name() {
    List<String> name_directory = new ArrayList<>();
    DirectCursorWrapper cursor = queryDirects(DirectoryTable.DIRECTORY_NAME, null, null);
    try {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            name_directory.add(cursor.getNamedirectory());
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return name_directory;

    directories = DirectLab.get(getActivity()).getDirectory_Name();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, directories);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

//mDatabaseDirectory = new DirectBaseHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase();
  //Cursor cursor = mDatabaseDirectory.query(DirectoryTable.DIRECTORY_NAME,
  //new String[]{"_id", DirectoryTable.Colums.NAMEDIR},
  //null,null,null,null,null);
  //final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
  //SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new  SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,cursor
  //,new String[]{DirectoryTable.Colums.NAMEDIR},new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
 // adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(18);
            mDirect.setName_directory(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
```

но дело в том что с большой БД будут проблемы с этими перегонками, + требуются еще спиннеры для продукта и описания, то есть с помощью запроса их извлекать, группировать и заполнять спиннер, пробовал с помощью старого `SimpleCursorAdapter` но не работает, по феншую бы с помощью `CursorLoader`, но к сожалению не нашел рабочего варианта в сети, возможно кто сталкивался разжует как это сделать?

Comment: пример [спиннера с CursorLoader](http://droidtips.ru/zapolnenie-spinner-iz-bazy-dannykh-cherez-cursor-loader/). Вы можете не использовать контент-провайдер и URI, а делать запросы напрямую, как в [этом примере](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html)

Comment: @pavlofff, вопрос еще в том как сделать для двух и более спиннеров в одном активити, как это обозначить в имплементированных методах LoaderCallbacks

Comment: ну здесь [вот писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612094/177345), как работать с несколькими курсорами, там есть идентификатор специально для целей различать лоудеры.

Comment: @pavlofff,к сожалению из вашей ссылки не ясно где указать каждому спиннеру к какому лоудеру он принадлежит... P/s спасибо за то что вы помогаете начинающим и не только, видел у вас много ответов которые помогли...